# Implementing OnClickListener in Android project with Ormlite

Tags: java, android, ormlite, onclicklistener

I am using Ormlite to implement the persistense layer and, as my application contains buttons that can be reused in several parts of the code, I would like to create a class that implements `View.OnClickListener` and extends `OrmLiteBaseActivity<DataBaseHelper>`, where `DataBaseHelper` is my helper for database operations. But when I do that and try to get a Dao to persist a object inside the `onClick()` method in my `Button` class, I get an `IllegalArgumentException`, saying that `onCreate()` was never called. I am doing that as below:

```
saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveProfileButton);
saveButton.setTag(profile);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new SaveButton());
```

And then, in the `SaveButton` class:

```
Dao<Profile, Long> profileDao = null;
Profile profileToSave = null;

try {
    profileDao = getHelper().getProfileDao();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();   
}
```

The error occurs when evaluating `getHelper`. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this thread can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702591/alert-dialog-inside-a-setclickonlistener-not-showing

Comment: Thank you @Niloct, but i don`t think that thread can help me. The problem is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an Activity() class like that, you can only use activities that have been started by the system, otherwise their Context won't be set up correctly.

In the Activity where you set the onClickListener, you should pass in (this) and handle the click event in there, or you could try:

EDITED:

```
saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveProfileButton);
saveButton.setTag(profile);
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new SaveButtonListener(this));
```

SaveButtonListener.java:

```
public class SaveButtonListener extends OnClickListener() { 

    private Activity context;

    public SaveButton(Activity c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(...) {
        ... your logic ...
        context.doSomething();
        context.findViewById(R.id.something);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second approach is exactly what i was trying to avoid, since the savebutton can not be re-used in another activity. Could you give me an example of how to pass the context in the SaveButton constructor so that getHelper from ormlite doesn`t give a IlegalState? What i am doing after reading your tip is pass the context in the constructor and use getHelperInternal(context), but inside onClick, when i do something like name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName); , it give me a nullpointer as well

Comment: Sorry @theelfismike, i meant IlegalArgumment

Comment: Just updated the example to pull the listener to a new class (.java file) that you can include elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much @theelfismik! I'm gonna try that. Looks just like what i wanted!